# how to apply cors feature to limited/specific domains or IPs in python bottle rest endpoint?

Tags: python, cors, response, bottle

```
from bottle import Bottle, response, request
import bottle
from bottle.ext import beaker
from bottle import redirect, request, response, route, run, static_file, error
from bottle import Bottle, get, ServerAdapter
from bottle.ext import beaker

#app = Bottle()
app = beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware(bottle.app())

def enable_cors(fn):
  def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
    # set CORS headers
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '100.200.100.500,100.300.100.400' # not working
    response.headers[
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
    response.headers[
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type,' \
                                          ' X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'
    response.add_header('Server', ' ')  # not able to make changes
    response.set_header('Server', ' ')  # not able to make changes

    if request.method != 'OPTIONS':
        # actual request; reply with the actual response
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
return _enable_cors

@route('/about', method=['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST'], strict_slash=True)
@enable_cors
def about():
   response.headers['content_type'] = 'text/ttt' # able to make changes
   response.headers['Server'] = ' ' # not able to make changes
   response.server = ' '
   print "request :: ",dict(request.headers)
   print response.iter_headers()
   #return HTTPResponse(content_type = 'text/plain', body="Tell me about yourself.")
   return "Tell me about yourself."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #bottle.run(host='localhost', port=5010, debug=True, server='paste')
    #app.run(host='localhost', port=5010, debug=True, server='paste')
    run(app=app, host='100.200.100.500', port=8080, debug=True, server='paste')
```

problems ::

1. not able to change response header parameter "Server"=" ". this problem is coming when trying to run server as paste.
2. not able to add limited Ips/domains to Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

any help please ?

Comment: I think it happens because of the paste server. It's somehow chaning the server after you set. The answer to your question is hard... it's about how to sub class the paste server and processing the response. It's very hard the documentation nowhere found. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @Raja Simon at least for reply.:)